# Using php variables for image location, use onclick to run through image gallery

Tags: javascript, php, image

I'm making a simple database query that returns several images. These images are stored in a php variable, with a javascript gallery showing one image at a time and using onclick function to run though the images. Its not working, please help!

My database query returns the images, each put into a variable. Variables then put into an array (because I thought it should be easier to run through an array)

```
    $img1       = $row['img1'];
$img2       = $row['img2'];
$img3       = $row['img3'];

$images = array($img1,$img2,$img3);
```

on the page itself the gallery section shows the first image fine

```
<div id="showImage">
<img src= " <?php echo "$images[0]" ?>" id="gallery">
<div id="rightHolder"><img onClick="Gallery(1)" src="images/arrow-right.png"></div>
<div id="leftHolder"><img onClick="Gallery(-1)" src="images/arrow-left.png"></div>
</div>
```

but the javascript wont up date the array key for $images onclick, so my second image is not loaded.

```
var imageCount = 1;
var totalImage = 3;

function Gallery(x) {
var image = document.getElementById('gallery');
imageCount  = imageCount + x;
if(imageCount > totalImage){imageCount = 1;}
if(imageCount < 1){imageCount = totalImage;}
image.src = "<?php echo $images["+ imageCount +"]?>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this: `image.src = "<?php echo $images["+ imageCount +"]?>";`

JS runs in the browser. JS does not have that PHP data.

You could try something like this in your JS file:

```
var images = "<?php echo implode(",", $images); ?>";
images = images.split(",");
```

With this piece of Js you can call an image by doing:

```
image.src = images[imageCount];
```

What it does is that it takes your PHP array, makes it a string seperated by commas. That string gets split on the comma which in Js would be an array.

Comment: thanks Matt. i tried that and it does not work. I dont understand why your JS would be able to get $images and mine wont.

Comment: The reason is that you are trying to output a php array data with a key set in JS while the key you are trying to access is not availible in php. You are trying to access $images["+ imageCount +"], but imageCount is not availible in php seeing it is a js variable. That is why you need to output the entire php array to JS and then access that js array with a js variable. Please try to understand that Js and PHP run in different stages from each other. You cannot use a variable from one in the other. Js runs in the browesr, php on the server

Comment: thanks Matt again. will it not work because I've stored my image locations in php variables, so js var images is an array of php variables $img1, $img2, $img3?

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is correct. To get a path you want to do (for example) $images[2]. But what you are trying to do now is $images[]. This is because php doesn't know "imageCount". Js knows that. that is why my solution takes everything in $images and outputs it like: "path1, path2, path3" (plain text). And JS will split on the "," and make an array of it. That way you can refrence the JS array with a Js variable.